Why do cabin alt warning and takeoff config warning sound the same?
Having 2 same-sounding warnings is counterintuitive. Why did the cockpit designer do this?

In a modern airliner warning sounds are typically played by a computer via speakers in the cockpit. Adding additional sounds is easy, just add a file to the computer and done.
The Boeing 737 however was designed in the 1960s. Playing sounds via a computer simply wasn't an option. Of course there were technologies available in the 60s to record and re-play sounds (like vinyl records), but none of these were suitable for use in an airliner's cockpit. So any warning sound has to be physically produced instead of just played over a speaker.
For example, the fire alarm on the 737 uses the fire warning bell. The sound is created by the actual bell in the cockpit (although I'm not sure if the sound comes from speakers in modern variants of the 737). The horn was chosen for three different situations:

Condition: An intermittent or steady warning horn sounds:

In flight an intermittent horn indicates the cabin altitude is at or above 10 000 ft;
On the ground an intermittent horn indicates an improper takeoff configuration
when advancing thrust levers to takeoff thrust; and
In flight a steady horn indicates an improper landing configuration.


(Helios Airways Flight 522 - Final Report)
While it's not ideal to use the same horn for three different situations, these should never really occur simultaneously and the specific situation should therefore be recognizable from context. It was therefore deemed acceptable to re-use the same horn.
Otherwise, two additional distinct sounds would need to be created in the cockpit. This would require additional equipment to produce the sound, which increases cost, weight and (most importantly) complexity. Any additional component installed in the cockpit can fail, which might result in costly groundings until a repair can be made.
The final report of the Helios accident clearly lists this as a finding:


The use of the same aural warning to signify two different situations (Takeoff
Configuration and Cabin Altitude) was not consistent with good Human
Factors principles.


(Helios Airways Flight 522 - Final Report)
Boeing therefore installed two lights on the forward panel to distinguish between the two situations with intermittent horn:

Takeoff Configuration and Cabin Altitude Warning Lights


(Boeing 737 FCOMv2 - 15.10.3 Warning Systems)

Related: Aircraft Alerting Systems Standardization Study. Volume II. Aircraft Alerting System Design Guidelines (1981)
